# Unexpected behavior mixing process.nextTick with async/await. How does the event loop work here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

My code:

```
async function run(){

    process.nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(1);
    });

    await (new Promise(resolve=>resolve()).then(()=>{console.log(2)}));

    console.log(3);

    process.nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(4);
    });

    new Promise(resolve=>resolve()).then(()=>{console.log(5)});

}

run();
```

My expected output is the numbers to print 1,2,3,4,5 in order, but instead I get:

```
1
2
3
5
4
```

As expected, the first `nextTick` is evaluated before the first `.then` callback, because `process.nextTick` and `.then` are both deferred to future ticks, and `process.nextTick` is declared before `.then`. So `1` and `2` are outputted in order as expected.

The code should not reach what is after `await` until after `.then` is resolved, and this works as expected, as `3` is outputted in the expected place.

Then essentially we have a repeat of the first part of the code, but this time `.then` is called before `process.nextTick`.

This seems like inconsistent behavior. Why does `process.nextTick` get called before the `.then` callback the first time around but not the second?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect it has something to do with promise callbacks being executed as so-called microtasks. [This youtube video](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1793) demonstrates the concept nicely.

Comment: I'm not up to full answer and interested in detailed explanation about what's going on in event loop, but that's because first `nextTick` is scheduled synchronously and second isn't.  This behaviour is specific to native promises. Any non-native promise implementation wouldn't have chance to schedule `then` before `nextTick`. `async` is executed synchronously until the first occurrence of `await`, this would be different if there was `await` before first `nextTick`.

Comment: As I commented on your earlier version of this question, the node.js event loop is very complicated.  It has multiple types of events that it services in a specific order.  But, it is further complicated by what it processes next also depends upon where it is in the cycle through the event loop priorities when something is scheduled.  It is not simple to understand or predict without a lot of work - I've personally studied it a long time and not completely figure it out.

Comment: I've long since come to conclusion that you should generally just think of all asynchronous operations as randomly ordered relatively to each other so if you NEED a specific order, then you should write your code to enforce that order.  Make one thing dependent upon the thing that must come before it so that no matter what the event loop does, your code still processes things in the order you need.

Comment: So, my explanation would be because of where in the event loop each `process.nextTick()` was called and that caused a different processing order relative to other types of events.  The first `process.nextTick()` was called when the event loop was in position A.  The second `process.nextTick()` was called after a `.then()` callback was processed which is a different part of the cycle of the event loop which means as the event loop continues processing the different types of events, it will hit `process.nextTick()` in a different order the 2nd time through.

Comment: Here's an analogy.  Imagine you're a delivery driver and your job is to make deliveries to 10 different restaurants.  At any point in time, any restaurant can put in a new order and you will deliver that new order at the next time you visit that restaurant.  But, you're on a preprogrammed route to hit the 10 restaurants in the same order each time.  One of the restaurants paid extra to be first in the order.  So, when you start out for the day, you always go to restaurant A first.

Comment: But, now suppose that after you've gone to restaurants A and B (and are on your way to C), restaurant A puts in a new order.  You're going to stay on your regular cycle and visit C, D, E ... and finish your cycle before you go to A.  So, how long it takes to get a new order to A depends entirely upon where you were in the cycle when the order was placed.

Comment: The same is true of different types of events in the event loop.  How soon an event is processed relative to other types of events can depend upon where the event loop was in its cycle between different types of events when the new event was added to the queue.  If it's at the start of the cycle when its added, it might be processed first.  But, if it's half-way through the cycle when its added, it may have to finish the cycle processing other types of events before it gets to that new event.

Comment: `.nextTick()` and native promises are different types of events, serviced at different points in the event loop cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the insight jfriend00 and others - I had just assumed that process.nextTick was more-or-less a shorthand for `new Promise(callback)`, but I'm learning it's really not that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js event queue is not a single queue.  It is actually a bunch of different queues and things like `process.nextTick()` and promise `.then()` handlers are not handled in the same queues.  So, events of different types are not necessarily FIFO.

As such, if you have multiple things that go in the event queue around the same time and you want them served in a specific order, the simplest way to guarantee that order is to write your code to force the order you want, not to try to guess exactly how two things are going to get sequenced that went into the queue around the same time.

It is true that two operations of the exact same type like two `process.nextTick()` operations or two resolved promise operations will be processed in the order they were put into the event queue.  But, operations of different types may not be processed in the order relative to each other that they were put in the event queue because different types of events are processed at different times in the cycle the event loop makes through all the different types of events.

It is probably possible to fully understand exactly how the event loop in node.js works for every type of event and predict exactly how two events that enter the event queue at about the same time will be processed relative to one another, but it is not easy.  It is further complicated by the fact that it also depends upon where the event loop is in its current processing when the new events are added to the event queue.

As in my delivery example in my earlier comments, when exactly a new delivery will be processed relative to other deliveries depends upon where the delivery driver is when the new order arrives in the queue.  The same can be true of the node.js event system.  If a new event is inserted while node.js is processing a timer event, it may have a different relative order to other types of events than if it node.js was processing a file I/O completion event when it was inserted.  So, because of this significant complication, I don't recommend trying to predict the execution order of asynchronous events of different types that are inserted into the event queue at about the same time.

And, I should add that native promises are plugged directly into the event loop implementation (as their own type of micro task) so a native promise implementation may behave differently in your original code than a non-native promise implementation.  Again a reason not to try to forecast exactly how the event loop will schedule different types of events relative to one another.

---

If the order of processing is important to your code, then use code to enforce a specific completion processing order.

As an example of how it matters what the event queue is doing when events are inserted into the event queue, your code simplified to this:

```
async function run(){

    process.nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(1);
    });

    await Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log(2)});

    console.log(3);

    process.nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(4);
    });

    Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log(5)});

}

run();
```

Generates this output:

```
1
2
3
5
4
```

But, simply change when the `run()` is called to be `Promise.resolve().then(run)` and the order is suddenly different:

```
async function run(){

    process.nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(1);
    });

    await Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log(2)});

    console.log(3);

    process.nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(4);
    });

    Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log(5)});

}

Promise.resolve().then(run);
```

Generates this output which is quite different:

```
2
3
5
1
4
```

You can see that when the code is started from a resolved promise, then other resolved promises that happen in that code get processed before `.nextTick()` events which wasn't the case when the code was started from a different point in the event queue processing.  This is the part that makes the event queue system very difficult to forecast.

---

So, if you're trying to guarantee a specific execution order, you have to either use all the same type of events and then they will execute in FIFO order relative to each other or you have to make your code enforce the execution order you want.  So, if you really wanted to see this order:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

You could use all promises which would essentially map to this:

```
async function run(){

    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log(1);
    })
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log(2)
    });

    await Promise.resolve().then(()=>{});

    console.log(3);

    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log(4)
    });

    Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log(5)});

}

run();
```

Or, you change the structure of your code so the code makes it always process things in the desired order:

```
async function run(){

    process.nextTick(async ()=>{
        console.log(1);
        await Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log(2)});
        console.log(3);
        process.nextTick(()=>{
            console.log(4);
            Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log(5)});
        });
    });
}

run();
```

Either of these last two scenarios will generate the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Well written and very beneficial! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the helpful comments that made me realize that not all javascript ways of deferring to a later tick are created equal. I had figured that `(new Promise()).then`, `process.nextTick`, even `setTimeout(callback,0)` would all be exactly the same but it turns out I can't assume that.

For now I'll leave here that the solution to my problem is simply to not use `process.nextTick` if it does not work in the expected order.

So I can change my code to (*Disclaimer this is not actually good async code in general*):

```
async function run(){

  process.nextTick(()=>{
    console.log(1);
  });

  await (new Promise(resolve=>resolve()).then(()=>{console.log(2)}));

  console.log(3);

  (new Promise(resolve=>resolve())).then(()=>{console.log(4)});

  (new Promise(resolve=>resolve())).then(()=>{console.log(5)});

 }

run();
```

Now I'm ensuring that `4` is logged before `5`, by making both of them the same type of async call. Making both of them use `process.nextTick` would also ensure that `4` logs before `5`.

```
async function run(){

  process.nextTick(()=>{
   console.log(1);
  });

  await (new Promise(resolve=>resolve()).then(()=>{console.log(2)}));

  console.log(3);

  process.nextTick(()=>{
    console.log(4)
  });

  process.nextTick(()=>{
    console.log(5)
  });

}

run();
```

This is a solution to my problem, but if anyone wants to provide a more direct answer to my question I'll be happy to accept.